# Resources to understand real world usage of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, applications

I've learned linear algebra basics at university and really liked it, so I decided to learn it more deeply. Secondly, I want to work in computer science and I think linear algebra knowledge could be really helpful.

Problem is that I don't know/learned much about its real world usage. I would be very grateful for any resources/algorithms/whatever which should help me to better understand its usage in real world.

Comment: That's very broad. Linear algebra is used so often, it often won't even get mentioned ...

Comment: You can search the old google's page ranking algorithm, I believe it heavily employed the power iteration of some sort. The SVD decomposition of a matrix is used in PCA to handle large data.

Comment: Maybe Gilbert Strang's textbook. $\qquad$

Comment: There's also spectral graph theory.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer (yet) because it's probably too advanced for you right now (you mention you've just learned the basics of linear algebra); however, [this](http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/books/itam_toc.html) is the table of contents for *Introduction to Applied Mathematics* by Gilbert Strang. He is a well-known expositor of linear algebra, and, as the contents shows, this book does not skimp on applications of linear algebra. There is more in the book than *just* linear algebra, but I think many of the chapters are relevant in this context.

Comment: Linear algebra and CS…I think Markov chains could be an interesting topic to learn next, when you're ready for the next theoretical step. Markov chains have applications in, amongst other CS subjects, artificial intelligence, and uses some linear algebra.

Answer (score 4):

Dan Kalman's tutotial on [SVD](http://www.math.umn.edu/~lerman/math5467/svd.pdf) describes singular value decomposition from a very friendly point of view, including applications for low rank approximation and image compression. When I taught linear algebra, I used it as a basis for my presentation of SVD and it was quite successful.

Kurt Bryan's and Tanya Leise's article on the [linear algebra behind Google's PageRank](http://www.math.umn.edu/~lerman/math5467/svd.pdf) algorithm is also very good and presents an important application.

Answer (score 3):

Much of present computer science deals with discrete structures, while you find linear algebra more often in scientific and engineering contexts. 
The examples that come to my mind are:

- 3D computer graphics using homogenous coordinates and matrices for
  scaling, rotation, translation
- image reconstruction using linear interpolation, least squares and that pseudo inverse of the normal equations